# SparkR has no GraphX functionality yet?

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr, spark-graphx

For a project we need to use GraphX+R, and the natural way is to use SparkR. I have checked everywhere but it seems that SparkR only has the machine learning libraries developed. There is no reference to GraphX. Does anyone know any R bindings for GraphX?

Comment: There are no bindings and considering that a) It would require Java wrappers b) GraphX development stopped almost completely this just won't happen. Some GraphFrames bindings are realistic but https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/108 not in progress.

Comment: @LostInOverflow you can post your comment as a wiki answer.

Comment: well that's too bad -- but thank you for finally giving a definitive answer to a question I have been asking for the past hour

Comment: A year later, GraphX development looks pretty active to me: https://github.com/apache/spark/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed